# Unable to deploy Run Job stage on Spinnaker using Kubernetes cloud provider

Tags: kubernetes, pipeline, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I’m currently unable to deploy run job stages using Kubernetes v1 provider on Spinnaker, by default when the stage is created I’m unable to choose the Account, the select box is empty.

By editing said stage as JSON, noticed that 'cloudProvider' is set to 'titus' by default, although I don’t have anything related to a Titus provider configured.

Changed that key to ‘kubernetes’, then the interface changes and allows me to choose which account, namespace, image, command and plenty of other settings I wish to use.

Then when I try to execute that pipeline it terminates inmediately, throwing the following error in spin-orca:

> [handlers-18] c.n.s.orca.q.handler.RunTaskHandler :  Error running
>   RunJobTask for pipeline[01CWF8DSF15F5EWY915YTKCYKD]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property ‘imageDescription’
>   on null object at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47)

From my understanding, the containers array is not being passed into Orca, but its showing properly constructed on the JSON editor.

This is an example of the JSON object generated by the interface:

```
{
      "account": "example-account",
      "annotations": {},
      "application": "website",
      "cloudProvider": "kubernetes",
      "cloudProviderType": "kubernetes",
      "cluster": {
        "application": "website",
        "capacity": {
          "desired": 1,
          "max": 1,
          "min": 1
        },
        "env": {},
        "resources": {
          "cpu": 1,
          "disk": 10000,
          "gpu": 0,
          "memory": 512,
          "networkMbps": 128
        },
        "retries": 0,
        "runtimeLimitSecs": 3600,
        "securityGroups": []
      },
      "containers": [
        {
          "args": [],
          "command": [],
          "envFrom": [],
          "envVars": [],
          "imageDescription": {
            "account": "gcr-docker-registry",
            "fromTrigger": true,
            "imageId": "gcr.io/example/example-backend (Tag resolved at runtime)",
            "registry": "gcr.io",
            "repository": "example/example-backend",
            "tag": ""
          },
          "imagePullPolicy": "IFNOTPRESENT",
          "limits": {
            "cpu": null,
            "memory": null
          },
          "livenessProbe": null,
          "name": "example-web-backend",
          "ports": [
            {
              "containerPort": 80,
              "hostIp": null,
              "hostPort": null,
              "name": "http",
              "protocol": "TCP"
            }
          ],
          "readinessProbe": null,
          "requests": {
            "cpu": null,
            "memory": null
          },
          "volumeMounts": []
        }
      ],
      "deferredInitialization": true,
      "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
      "labels": {},
      "name": "Run Job",
      "namespace": "staging",
      "nodeSelector": {},
      "organization": "",
      "refId": "3",
      "registry": "",
      "repository": "",
      "requisiteStageRefIds": [],
      "tag": "",
      "type": "runJob",
      "volumeSources": [],
      "waitForCompletion": true
  }
```

Currently running Spinnaker version 1.10.5, installed using Halyard 1.12.0-20181024113436, over a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

Comment: Is there an `imageDescription` on each container?

Comment: not sure what you meant, on the json that is used to construct the stage theres a containers key which is an array, and have 1 element which is an object and indeed it has an imageDescription key, which contains the docker registry information and other stuff.

Comment: Just edited the main post to show an example of the stage json.